# Prevent Alphabetical Dedupping

Tags: sql, duplicates, sql-order-by, partitioning, row-number

[image]

I have a table full of OrderIDs and Products that correlate with the order. The table lists the products in the order they were added into the users cart.

FirstProduct = row_number() over (partition by i.orderid order by i.[name])

^I then use this to help give each product a row.

[image]

The problem I'm running into is it keeps listing the products in alphabetical order, opposed to the correct order listed in the above table. Is there a way to prevent it from listing the products in alphabetical order and keeping the sequence in the previous table constant?

Comment: SQL tables return *unordered* result sets, unless you explicitly use `ORDER BY`.  Clearly you are not.  Add in the `ORDER BY` you want; it is not clear from your question.

Comment: Why and where is it important to you to show ordered data ? In the table ?